# jQuery: How to open a new modal dialog or popup window

Tags: jquery, css, modal-dialog

There's a login button at the bottom of the homepage.
I want to open a new frame that works like another web page when I click on the button! But **the popup window should be opened inside the homepage** and located in the center of the homepage! It should be smaller than the homepage.

All I've been looking for is how to open a new tab or a new window.
I want to know how to open a popup window located in center of the homepage.

Comment: Your question is somehow vague. can you include some visual examples of your purpose?

Comment: Now that I know it's called Modal, I'll give it a try and ask for your help if it doesn't work out, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is JavaScript solution from [w3school.com](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_modal)

Try it :

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```css
/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 20px;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: #aaaaaa;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
<button id="myBtn">Open Modal</button>

<!-- The Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <p>Place Your Content Here ..</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

These two answers, using jQuery, will quickly explain how to create your own pop-up modal dialog box *(also known as a lightbox)*.

[jQuery Lightbox appearing blank](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38171187/jquery-lightbox-appearing-blank/38171447#38171447)

[Prevent modal from scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54764414/prevent-modal-from-scrolling/54777154#)

> A modal is just a pop-up dialog box that: (a) pops-up overtop of other content, and (b) usually prevents you from interacting with the underlying page until it is closed.

and

> A lightbox is just a regular DIV structure that has been styled position:absolute or position:fixed to remove it from the normal HTML flow. It is then hidden, and displayed when desired upon a button click or other detectable event (mouseover, ajax.done, etc).

Positioning the dialog and making it look great(er) is the job of CSS.

Note that you can also use a library/framework, like Bootstrap or jQueryUI *(a separate, complementary library that works exactly like jQuery and provides many additional features)*, to provide pre-fab dialog boxes with skookum CSS that already have many working bits pre-done for you.

https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap4/bootstrap_modal.asp

https://jqueryui.com/dialog/

It is *most* important, however, for you to understand what a modal dialog *is* before you choose to use a library. And, since it only takes 5 minutes to comprehend the first linked answer above, it is easily done.